# Robotino make error

Tags: ros, robotino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am using ros fuerte and ubuntu 12.04, I am trying to use the robotino stacks and have followed the instructions from http://wiki.openrobotino.org/index.php?title=ROS, I have downloaded the api2 packages on my laptop running ubuntu 12.04. The CF card has an image of version 2.4 (I think api1).  I know I need to update my CF card to api2. But I still expected the make to be successful (even if the connection to robotino will fail until I update the CF card to api2). I have added the robotino-ros-pkg to my ROS PACKAGE PATH. When I run the comand : $ rosmake --pre-clean robotino

I get the following error at the end:

### Linking CXX executable ../bin/robotino_camera_node
/usr/local/robotino/api2/lib/librec_robotino_api2.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/robotino_camera_node] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/samme/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino/robotino_node/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/robotino_camera_node.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/samme/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino/robotino_node/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/samme/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino/robotino_node/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package robotino_node written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/samme/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121231-130653/robotino_node/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< robotino_node [FAIL] [ 7.27 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package robotino_node.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Cleaned 51 packages.
[ rosmake ] Built 47 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/samme/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121231-130653

Any ideas why I am getting this error?  /usr/local/robotino/api2/lib/librec_robotino_api2.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Thanks and best regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51246/robotino-make-error/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I realized I had installed the i386 api2 packages instead of the amd64 api2 packages. I then recieved another float conversion error problem so I added this line to the cmakelists.txt:

add_definitions (-Wall -O3 -funroll-loops -fpermissive)

and the build was successful.

regards

Khalid

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0